# Importing a costmap layer from a pgm

Tags: ros, navigation, costmap, pgm, layered-costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've got a costmap that uses a static, obstacle, inflation, and another custom layer that I wrote. Is there an easy way to load an additional layer drawn on a PGM grayscale image? If not, I could probably manage to analyze the image with python or C++ and add values to a new costmap layer from there. Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215161/importing-a-costmap-layer-from-a-pgm./) by [mattc_vec](https://answers.ros.org/users/22656/mattc_vec/) on ROS Answers with karma: 50 on 2015-08-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is actually what the `map_server` is for. See [the documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/map_server) for more details.

It takes a  grayscale image (`.pgm` should work), where whiter pixels are free and darker pixels are occupied.
Remember to also configure the respective `yaml` file correctly, as described in the documentation.

This map can then be loaded in another static map layer, as described [here](http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d/hydro/staticmap).

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2015-08-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3